How does `EventBus.TriggerContextsetResumeCheckpoint()` work?
I'm currently looking at the "Apply Best Practices for Writing Platform Event Triggers" Trailhead where EventBus.TriggerContext.setResumeCheckpoint() is apparently used to set "checkpoints" for resuming when the trigger fails.
However, it isn't 100% clear to me how this or the checkpoint can function.
Okay, the Trailhead suggests this will "set Replay ID after which to resume event processing in a new trigger execution", but that still leaves open questions.
But we never get the checkpoint anywhere, we just get the values from Trigger.New (or something which received values from Trigger.New....
Do I correctly infer that setResumeCheckpoint() if, for some reason, we need/want to process the events in any order other than the default order provided by Trigger.New?
And, moreover, if our process (for whatever reasons) requires data from earlier events when processing later ones, we can't expect that data to remain available within Trigger.New when we are resuming?
For example, if I wanted to have some bulkified process, where I would group together all events which have the same value for event.Foo__c, and then iterate over the different groupings and do something with each one of them, would it still be possible to create servicable resume checkpoints?
(Of course, this begs questions of whether/when bulk processing should even be applied to any sort of events...  It seems to me that Microsoft has made it more difficult to do such when creating Azure Function Apps with an event trigger...)


Do I correctly infer that setResumeCheckpoint() if, for some reason, we need/want to process the events in any order other than the default order provided by Trigger.New?

No.

And, moreover, if our process (for whatever reasons) requires data from earlier events when processing later ones, we can't expect that data to remain available within Trigger.New when we are resuming?

Unless you store that data somewhere, it's gone. The checkpoint advances to the next replay ID, creating a new batch. You might need this if, for example, you get 2000 events, but only have enough CPU time to handle 1000 of them; the remaining 1000 will be part of the next execution.

For example, if I wanted to have some bulkified process, where I would group together all events which have the same value for event.Foo__c, and then iterate over the different groupings and do something with each one of them, would it still be possible to create servicable resume checkpoints?

Certainly. You could process each batch of bulkified data group by Foo__c, set the checkpoint after each group, then check if you have enough governor limits, and terminate early if you don't. You'd be able to handle as much data per event as possible, while not losing any progress.
However, since you lose everything before the checkpoint, you'd have to make sure that the replay ID is set one before the first event that represents a Foo__c group that has not been processed yet.

(Of course, this begs questions of whether/when bulk processing should even be applied to any sort of events... It seems to me that Microsoft has made it more difficult to do such when creating Azure Function Apps with an event trigger...)

There's plenty of reasons why these events might be in bulk. Apex Code, Data Loader, etc, etc could generate a lot of events in a short period, and it's more efficient to handle these events in bulk than one at a time.

Hi @sfdcfox.  Thanks for the response, but I'm not entirely clear how setResumeCheckpoint() might work in a context where we don't process the events in Trigger.New order... Let's say for example, I break Trigger.New into groups which have ReplayIds {1, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 8}, and {3, 6} (for simplicity)... What would I set the ReplayId to after I finish the first group so it would be able to resume if there is a problem processing the second group?  Or what if the first group has partial success, would I be able to create a checkout for that?

@BrianKessler You'd set the checkpoint to one before the first member of the lowest indexed unprocessed group. In your example, processing groups in order, you'd set the checkpoint as 1 after group 1, 2 after group 2, and then 9 after group 3, to indicate that all records were processed. Note: this means if you stop processing after the second group, Trigger.new would start at 3, 4, 5... so groups you've already processed would be present in later batches. You'd have to arrange to account for that, or possibly accept duplicate work might happen.

@BrianKessler As a more complicated example, {1, 2, 3, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 8}, {9, 10}, would set checkpoints at 3, 8, and 10 as the three groups are processed.

okay... I think that makes sense...  In practice, I imagine that can get ugly, but not to the point of being unworkable...

@BrianKessler Certainly no walk in the park, but I once wrote a faux multitasking callout mechanism in Apex, so I don't think this would be as scary as that.

Apex may be missing some bells and whistles, but you can do some pretty amazing stuff with it when you put your mind to it.  :-)
